# Is there a way to group by monthly period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have data that I need to query to find out which person spent the most over a 9 month period. My data spans 5 years and the 9 month period may consist of months from one year and through the next year.

For example October 2005 through July 2006.

I've managed to group by personid and month and year, but is there a way for me to group by 9 month periods? I figured if I can do that then I can just find the max value in that grouping.

Comment: Yes there are many ways to go about it, but we need more information to be able to help you. What have you tried? what do your tables look like? ect.

Comment: Rolling or Incremental periods?

Comment: How do you define the 9month intervals?  Do you mean a single specific 9 months, or are there multiple fixed, pre-planned intervals, or do you want to check every possible 9 months?  You need to be a lot more clear as to your requirements..

Comment: Yea definitely rolling. @JohnCappelletti

Comment: OK then.  Look at the answer I provided.   The first section will show results for a rolling period.   The dates can be adjusted as necessary,   Do you have a date table or would you be interested in my UDF?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I don't have a date table actually. The table contains the dates of all the transactions, and the personid of the person that spent the money. Can I just use that same table to create the intervals, as you did?

Comment: Select DateR1
      ,DateR2=DateAdd(DD,-1,DateAdd(MM,9,DateR1))
 From (Select distinct DateR1=DateAdd(DD,1+-Day([MyDateField]),cast([MyDateField] as date)) from [MyTable]) A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a date table or in my case a udf

```
Select DateR1,DateR1,PersonID,TotalSpent=sum(Spent)
 From  [SomeTable] A
 Join (
        Select DateR1=DateAdd(MM,-9,RetVal)
              ,DateR2=DateAdd(DD,-1,RetVal)
         from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2005-10-01','2016-07-31','MM',1)
      ) B on A.DataDate between B.DateR1 and B.DateR2
 Group By DateR1,DateR2,PersonID 
 Order by 1,3
```

The sub-query returns

```
DateR1      DateR2
2005-01-01  2005-09-30
2005-02-01  2005-10-31
2005-03-01  2005-11-30
2005-04-01  2005-12-31
2005-05-01  2006-01-31
2005-06-01  2006-02-28
...
2015-09-01  2016-05-31
2015-10-01  2016-06-30
2015-11-01  2016-07-31
```

So it just becomes a small matter of aggregating data between date ranges

BTW this is a rolling 9 Month

If not Rolling

```
Select DateR1,DateR2=DateAdd(DD,-1,DateR2) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2005-10-01','2016-07-31','MM',9)
```

Returns

```
DateR1      DateR2
2005-10-01  2006-06-30
2006-07-01  2007-03-31
2007-04-01  2007-12-31
2008-01-01  2008-09-30
2008-10-01  2009-06-30
2009-07-01  2010-03-31
2010-04-01  2010-12-31
2011-01-01  2011-09-30
2011-10-01  2012-06-30
2012-07-01  2013-03-31
2013-04-01  2013-12-31
2014-01-01  2014-09-30
2014-10-01  2015-06-30
2015-07-01  2016-03-31
2016-04-01  2016-07-30
```

Comment: Thanks John this looks like what I needed. I'll modify it to fit my use case and see if I can manage the right answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you explain what RetVal is?
I only have one table and it contains the amount spent, personid of spender, and the transaction date. From this I have to find the biggest spender in any rolling 9 month period.

Comment: RetVal is just a field name provided by the UDF return table.   Call it a lack of imagination on my part

Comment: I was able to modify it to fit my table, thanks again for the help it worked perfectly!

Comment: This is the fun stuff.   Happy to help.